# Adding post fields in wp-json/wp/v2/search

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to add the post (pages, posts) excerpt in the `wp-json/wp/v2/search` get endpoint but this endpoint seems to not take into account the `register_rest_field` method.

```php
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {

register_rest_field('post', 'excerpt', array(
    'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
        die(var_dump($post_arr));
        return $post_arr['excerpt'];
    },
));

register_rest_field('page', 'excerpt', array(
    'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
        die(var_dump($post_arr));
        return $post_arr['excerpt'];
    },
));

});
```

This causes `wp-json/wp/v2/pages` and `wp-json/wp/v2/posts` to die, but `wp-json/wp/v2/search` works perfectly, although it renders posts and pages.

Any idea how I can add my excerpt to the results of the `wp-json/wp/v2/search` route?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to, you're meant to use the response to retrieve the posts at their own endpoints, that's why each item has a reference to its location in the REST API in `_links` under `self`

Comment: I wondered about that too, but when you `_embed=self`, things like `content`, `meta`, etc still aren't there. It shouldn't require a 2nd HTTP request, should it?

Comment: Related: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51596

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the search endpoint, the object type (the first parameter for `register_rest_field()`) is `search-result` and not the post type (e.g. `post`, `page`, etc.).

So try with this, which worked for me:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    // Registers a REST field for the /wp/v2/search endpoint.
    register_rest_field( 'search-result', 'excerpt', array(
        'get_callback' => function ( $post_arr ) {
            return $post_arr['excerpt'];
        },
    ) );
} );
```

Comment: In what world this is not in the "Modifying Responses" documentation. Every day with WP is another day in hell. Thanks!

Comment: @dievardump you should join the Make WP `#docs` channel and ask, the answer is likely that they don't have the needed volunteers to do all the things

Answer (score 2):

The highest voted answer is not correct... Please use following one, as there is no "excerpt" in $post_arr, so that means you need to "get it".

```
/**
 * Add excerpt to search API endpoint.
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    // Registers a REST field for the /wp/v2/search endpoint.
    register_rest_field( 'search-result', 'excerpt', array(
        'get_callback' => function ( $post_arr ) {
            return get_the_excerpt( $post_arr['id'] );
        },
    ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Embeds only return fields that have the `embed` context. You can add embed to the context specified in the schema using the `"rest_{$post_type}_item_schema"` filter.

-- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51596

Here's an example of that. Note that parent fields like `content` need to have the context added in order for child fields like `content.rendered` to show up.

```php
add_filter( 'rest_' . POST_TYPE . '_item_schema', function( $schema ) {
    $schema['properties']['content']['context'][]                           = 'embed';
    $schema['properties']['content']['properties']['rendered']['context'][] = 'embed';

    return $schema;
} );
```

That feels a bit more "correct" to me than using `register_rest_field()`.